# How can I downgrade my spyder version in Anaconda?

Tags: anaconda, spyder, anaconda3

I have a course where I have been instructed to use Anaconda with spyder. Due to the newer versions of spyder not being compatible with all of the commands the professor wants to use (I dont know which ones), we were asked to downgrade the spyder version of a course specific environment to spyder 4. The following lines of code were given and run in the prompt:

```
conda install spyder=4
conda install spyder-notebook -c conda-forge
```

The second command ran as expected. However, when trying to install spyder 4, the following was output:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - spyder=4

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

In anaconda-navigator, I am able to install all of the Spyder 5.x.x versions, but nothing older than that. I sadly don't know what build I am running, but it is the newest macOS (M1/M2) installation availible on the anaconda website at this time of writing. I have a mac M1 myself.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Like downgrade anaconda somehow?

I have attempted to do some trouble shooting myself, and tried to use `conda install spyder=4 -c conda-forge`, but that did not help either.

Comment: It doesn't look as if the conda or conda-forge channels have any version of Spyder earlier than 5.x for the osx-arm64 (i.e. Apple Silicon) platform. Can you get some clarification of why and how Spyder 5.x isn't compatible, and a list of the packages you need for the course? In general rather than trying to downgrade packages in an existing environment it's better to rebuild the env from an amended package list (which you can maintain in a requirements file). If you must use Spyder 4 then you might be able to install the Intel Mac version of Anaconda instead, which should run in emulation.